# How to avoid the execution of an idempotent code?

Tags: java

I have a class which has an init method which does initialization of the member variables.So I wanted the execution of that code to be run only once for any number execution of that class. So how to go about that?

please let me know if the question is not clear.

EDIT:

Actually I have some legacy code with thousands of classes having the big init methods. which does the initialization(with all static values) of the member variables.

And say suppose In a main method if I have a reference to any of these class. and I run the main method for 100 times then all 100 times it executes the same method which is a performance hit. So i thought of having the member variables as static and do the initialization only once for any number of execution. but I thought it will lead to a OutOfMemory as all the objects for those thousands of classes will remain in jvm till it dies.

Hope it is clear now.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's unclear. Either you want a single instantiation of a class (a singleton), or you want a second call to `init()` on a given instantiation to fail or be a no-op. The latter would simply involve setting a boolean in the class and checking it (using an atomic if thread safety was needed) or using `final` member variables and setting them in the constructor rather than in `init()`.

Comment: What do you mean by "any number of execution of the class" ran once in total or once per instance or something else?

Comment: Remember that "Premature optimization is the root of all evil". Don't make assumptions, but measure the performance hits. You will be astonished to discover how well tuned are nowadays the JVMs.

Comment: What's really unclear is why you want to avoid multiple executions of **idempotent** code, when the whole point of idempotent routines is that they can be safely executed multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

do (not) use singleton anti-pattern, with a static class method.
http://thetechcandy.wordpress.com/2009/12/02/singletons-is-anti-pattern/

Comment: Anti-pattern of the non-singleton. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever heard about constructors?
http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-constructors

Comment: If you see my profile, I have more than 100 votes in java tag. And you are asking me about constructor.

Comment: @GuruKid - and yet, you don't have the first clue as to what a "singleton" is? Or static members?

Comment: It's rudely put but there's a point there, you could maybe describe why in your context you need an init as well as a constructor this may lead to better answers.

Comment: The number of tags means that you are diligent, but doesn't mean that you are smart...and from the way you asked this question I think that the former option suits you more...

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just make this init method a class method ?
(In java, using the "static" keyword)

Comment: If I do that then all the objects will be in jvm untill i terminate. Which may lead to OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: @Guru how large are these Objects?

Answer (score 0):

> **So I wanted the execution of that code to be run only once for any number execution of that class.**

There's no built in language-feature for this I'm afraid. You'll have to encapsulate it using something like

```
if (!initialized) {
    // init ...
    initialized = true;
}
```

(But make sure to declare such `init` methods as `synchronized` so two threads don't both initialize an object due to caching or race conditions etc.)

Btw... it's a bit unclear what you mean by *"execution of that class"*. Do you mean "any number of *instantiations* of that class"?

Answer (score 0):

1) use the static block code:

```
public class MyClass {
    static {
     // do your thing here, it gets executed just once at class loading
     }
}
```

2) use a constructor, as others have previously pointed